# How to structure GA Enhanced Analytics to capture data about an event ticket sales website?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I want to integrate [GA Enhanced Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) (GEA) to [GO2CINEMA](https://go2cinema.com/).

GO2CINEMA lists movie showtimes and allows to purchase cinema tickets. I am using GO2CINEMA as an example, however the same problem applies to any event ticketing site.

The problem I am facing is that GEA [product data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data) fields do not translate well to ephemeral/ time- and geospecific products:

```
id          text        Yes*    The product ID or SKU (e.g. P67890). *Either this field or name must be set.
name        text        Yes*    The name of the product (e.g. Android T-Shirt). *Either this field or id must be set.
brand       text        No      The brand associated with the product (e.g. Google).
category    text        No      The category to which the product belongs (e.g. Apparel). Use / as a delimiter to specify up to 5-levels of hierarchy (e.g. Apparel/Men/T-Shirts).
variant     text        No      The variant of the product (e.g. Black).
price       currency    No      The price of a product (e.g. 29.20).
quantity    integer     No      The quantity of a product (e.g. 2).
coupon      text        No      The coupon code associated with a product (e.g. SUMMER_SALE13).
position    integer     No      The product's position in a list or collection (e.g. 2).
```

"product" ID has little relevance when the product (specific event ticket) is not going to exist more than couple of days.

In the context of GO2CINEMA, a event has the following key information associated with it:

- ID
- datetime
- movie information
- cinema and venue information
- screening attributes [3D, IMAX, etc]
- price

Also, important metrics are:

- Relative time until the event (e.g. event starts in 30 minutes)
- Relative distance to the venue (e.g. venue is 500 meters away)

I was thinking of using:

- "category" to capture week/ day time, e.g. "{Sunday, Monday, ..}/{Morning, Afternoon, Evening}/{Starting in less than 1 hour, Starting in less than 3 hours, ...}"
- "brand" to capture the cinema/ venue, e.g. "Odeon/Leicester Square" (though it looks like "/" does not achieve the same result as category)

However, this still leaves out the relative distance, price and movie.

How does one incorporate all of this information in a meaningful way?